# How do I inherit class functions into a Django Model?

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I'm trying to inherit functions from a class into a Django model so I can call the class functions using an instance of the model.  In the below example, I want to inherit the class DoStuff into the model MainModel so I would receive the following output:

```
>>> m = MainModel(var1=3, var2=4)
>>> m.do_stuff.add()
7
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class DoStuff:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add(self):
        return self.x + self.y

class MainModel(models.Model):
    var1 = models.IntegerField()
    var2 = models.IntegerField()
    do_stuff = DoStuff(var1, var2)  #How do I correctly do this?
```

I know this problem may seem a bit trivial, but it's a simplification of a greater issue I'm trying to solve.

Thank you for reviewing my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a property that will use the `var1` and `var2`, so:

```
class MainModel(models.Model):
    var1 = models.IntegerField()
    var2 = models.IntegerField()
    
    @property
    def do_stuff(self):
        return DoStuff(self.var1, self.var2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Willem!